# Defining local equilibrium within a fluid splited in elementary volumes

Tags: thermodynamics, fluid-dynamics, equilibrium

I have been staring a paragraph of my fluid mechanics book for a long time and would like to ask to the community here how I could understand the meaning of $\delta A$, $\nabla A$ and $\bar A$ in this context. The chapter is about showing that thermodynamics can still be used with local equilibriums even if a global equilibrium doesn't exist :

> System split into elementary volumes, of linear dimension $\lambda$ (volume $\lambda^3$), big
> enough to contain a number, N, of particles sufficient to define a
> thermodynamic property A (T, p, …), $\delta A / Ᾱ<<1$ (proportional to 1/√N)

> Macroscopic gradient of A (system far from equilibrium) → Fluctuations of A.

> Local equilibrium when:
>
> 1. the fluctuations of A are small, $\delta A/Ᾱ<<1$
> 2. the variation of A due to the macroscopic gradient ∇A is smaller than the
>    fluctuations $\delta A$, ∇A<<$\delta A$

1. $\bar A$: I believe this is the mean value of $A$ within the macroscopic fluid. For instance, the global temperature of the water in the water pot.
2. $\delta A$: the "fluctuations" of $A$ ? Does it mean that $\delta A = |\bar A - A|$ ? If it is correct, the formula $\delta A / \bar A \ll 1$ means that $A$ is very close to $\bar A$ in every elementary volume. Doesn't seem logic to me: will every drop in my water pot have the same temperature ?
3. $\nabla A$: I absolutely don't understand that one. How could you compare a gradient, thus a variation of A, to a value of A itself ($\nabla A \ll \delta A$) ? It would be like compairing the speed and the acceleration of a car: it doesn't have the same units.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will try to answer:

1. The overbar is usually used to denote the/an average of a value/quantity/variable. So your guess is probably correct.
2. The notation $\delta A$ usually denotes some small change or fluctuation (not necessarily infinitesimal) of the variable $A$ and $\delta A/\bar{A} \ll 1$ is almost always used to say exactely what you guessed: $A$ is close to $\bar{A}$ or the small change $\delta A$ is much smaller than $\bar{A}$. This does **not** mean that that the temperature in your water pot has the same temperature everywhere. It just means that if there are changes in temperature, they are small compared to the average temperature.
3. You are right about the unit mismatch. I believe that the author wanted to say that the gradient $\nabla A$ of $A$ must me much smaller than the change $\delta A$ divided by the length scale $\lambda$ of the elementary volumes.

I have the impression that these conditions are used to say one thing: The macroscopic gradient must be so small that the non-equlibrium phenomena are negligible. However, there are fluctuations in space and in time, and the author did not specify which. So I would write the two conditions as

1. $\frac{\partial A}{\partial t} \mathrm{d}t \ll \bar{A}$ (only fluctuations with time)
2. $\frac{\partial A}{\partial x} \lambda \ll \frac{\partial A}{\partial t} \mathrm{d}t$ (macroscopic change with respect to spatial direction $x$ times your spatial "resolution" $\lambda$ = "fluctuation in space" is much smaller than your fluctuation in time)

Please note that the gradient $\nabla A$ is usually a vector when $A$ is a scalar such as temperature or pressure. Thus, one needs a three-dimensional "resolution vector" $\mathbf{\lambda}$ to specify a fluctuation in space.